# Python: ImportError: No module named v1 for b2-sdk-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7

I'm trying to use [Backblaze/b2-sdk-python](https://github.com/Backblaze/b2-sdk-python). I think I managed to install it by just doing `pip install b2sdk`

```
$ pip install b2sdk
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: b2sdk in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (0.1.8)
Requirement already satisfied: futures>=3.0.5; python_version < "3.2" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from b2sdk) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: arrow<0.13.1,>=0.8.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from b2sdk) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from b2sdk) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: logfury>=0.1.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from b2sdk) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34>=1.1.6; python_version < "3.4" in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from b2sdk) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from b2sdk) (44.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.5.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from b2sdk) (4.43.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from b2sdk) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.functools-lru-cache>=1.2.1; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from arrow<0.13.1,>=0.8.0->b2sdk) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from arrow<0.13.1,>=0.8.0->b2sdk) (1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from logfury>=0.1.2->b2sdk) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->b2sdk) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->b2sdk) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->b2sdk) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->b2sdk) (2019.11.28)
```

But following the [Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/Backblaze/b2-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/source/quick_start.rst) after I do

```
>>> from b2sdk.v1 import *
```

Then I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named v1
```

May I ask what is going on?

I'm using Python 2.7.16 on macOS.

Comment: I suspect something's wrong with your installation of `b2sdk`. Did you try to uninstall and re-install?

Comment: I tried with Python 3 on Linux and it worked, perhaps is only compatible with Python 3.

Comment: I tested this with python 2.7 on MacOS - works just fine.